# Mapper unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I am having difficulities with Automapper and i hope you could help. I am trying to map from DailyCourses to DailyCoursesSearch but i keep getting an exception. I get that there is some issue with the mapping but i have tried to switch the object position, made sure that all tzpes are the same treid to map from member to member but no success. It does work with another classes.

This is the error i have

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
Mapping types:
Object -> DailyCourseSearch
System.Object -> Core.Contracts.Models.DailyCourseSearch
```

And these are all classes mentioned

```
public class DailyCourses
{
  public DateTimeOffset? CourseDate { get; set; }
            
  public IEnumerable<DailyCourse> Items { get; set; }
}
            
  public class DailyCoursesSearch
 {
    public DateTimeOffset? CourseDate { get; set; }
            
    public IEnumerable<DailyCourseSearch> Items { get; set; }
 }
            
 public class DailyCourseSearch
 {
   public string CountryName { get; set; } = null!;
            
   public string CurrencyName { get; set; } = null!;
            
   public string Amount { get; set; }
            
   public string CountryCode { get; set; } = null!;
            
   public string Course { get; set; }
   }

  public class DailyCourse
    {
        [Required]
        public string CountryName { get; set; } = null!;

        [Required]
        public string CurrencyName { get; set; } = null!;

        //TODO to short
        [Required]
        public string Amount { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// ISO 3-letter code
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        public string CountryCode { get; set; } = null!;

        //TODO to double
        [Required]
    public string Course { get; set; }
    }
        
        
 public class MapperTest
 {
  [Test]
  public void Mapping()
  {
     var dailyCourses = new DailyCourses();
     dailyCourses.Items = new List<DailyCourse>()
     {
       new DailyCourse()
       {
            Amount = "TEst"
        }
       };
        
         var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<DailyCourses, DailyCoursesSearch>().ForMember(a => a.Items, o => o.MapFrom(y => y.Items));
            cfg.CreateMap<DailyCourse, DailyCourseSearch>();
        });
                var mapper = new Mapper(config);
        
        
           mapper.Map<DailyCourseSearch>(dailyCourses);
          }
      }
    
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
     }
```

Comment: I bet your `CurseDate` has been `DateTime.Now` for a while? :D

Comment: So.. does your automapper know how to map `DailyCourse` <-> `DailyCourseSearch` so it can map `DailyCourses.Items` (an `IEnumerable<DailyCourse>`) into `DailyCoursesSearch.Items` (an `IEnumerable<DailyCourseSearch>`) ?

Comment: sorry? I dont see any DateTime.Now in the posted code

Comment: It was a joke, implying that you've been cursing the code for some time.. ;)

Comment: Sorry , i really have been stuck on this for a while :D Well, yes thats what i thought but even adding cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable<DailyCourse>, IEnumerable<DailyCourseSearch>>(); didnt help

Comment: @Progman done, there really isnt more to it

Comment: *even adding `cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable<DailyCourse>, IEnumerable<DailyCourseSearch>>();` didnt help* - You don't need to map enumerables, just the things inside them: [docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html) "*AutoMapper only requires configuration of element types, not of any array or list type that might be used*"

Comment: `CurseDate` -> `CourseDate`, JIC =)

Comment: @Progman apologies i thought that i added it

Comment: @purr It's a simple typo, `mapper.Map<DailyCourseSearch>(dailyCourses);` -> `mapper.Map<DailyCoursesSearch>(dailyCourses);`. You have a mapping from `DailyCourses` to `DailyCoursesSearch` (with `s`) , but not to `DailyCourseSearch` (without `s`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a really hard to spot error in your code and just found it, when writing a complete [running example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B57Tqz)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using AutoMapper;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dailyCourses = new DailyCourses();
        dailyCourses.Items = new List<DailyCourse>()
        {
            new DailyCourse { Amount = "Test" }
        };

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<DailyCourse, DailyCourseSearch>();
            cfg.CreateMap<DailyCourses, DailyCoursesSearch>()
                .ForMember(a => a.Items, o => o.MapFrom(y => y.Items));
        });

        var mapper = new Mapper(config);
        
        var search = mapper.Map<DailyCoursesSearch>(dailyCourses);
        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(search);
        
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}

public class DailyCourses
{
    public DateTimeOffset? CurseDate { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<DailyCourse> Items { get; set; }
}

public class DailyCoursesSearch
{
    public DateTimeOffset? CurseDate { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<DailyCourseSearch> Items { get; set; }
}

public class DailyCourseSearch
{
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyName { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }

    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
}

public class DailyCourse
{
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyName { get; set; } 
    public string Amount { get; set; }

    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
}
```

The error in your code is this line:

```
mapper.Map<DailyCourseSearch>(dailyCourses);
```

and it should be this code to work:

```
mapper.Map<DailyCoursesSearch>(dailyCourses);
```

So the reason is a simple typo in your code and this question should be closed.

Comment: Ah waw, thats stupid error. Thjank you so much!!!! You just saved me few hours and pottentionally from going crazy